# Menu items are not showing on my android phone

Tags: android, android-studio

I am running this code on my android phone and i am unable to see menu items on my android phone but when i run this on emulator, i can see menu items.
Please help . Here is the screenShot of.

[image: Emulator] [image: Mobile]

```
<item android:title="About Us"
    android:id="@+id/aboutUs_ID"/>
<item android:title="Preferences"
    android:id="@+id/preferences_ID"/>
```

java code in activity

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    MenuInflater myMenu = getMenuInflater();
    myMenu.inflate(R.menu.menu_file, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Can you add the code for your Activity class please ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use below solution;

**res/menu/main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="Color Theam"
    app:showAsAction="never" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_appMahiti"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/tab_refrence"
    app:showAsAction="never" />

</menu>
```

Here is the code snippiest you can add in your activity class

**Activity.java**

```
 @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; 
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();
    switch (id) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
             // perform operation or display message
            Toast.makeText(this, "CLick me", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
         case R.id.action_appMahiti:
            // perform operation 
            startActivity(new Intent(this, XYZ.class));
            break;
     }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

I will suggest to try to use above solution.

Comment: java code is working fine but both menu and menu items are not showing on my mobile. And on emulator these are visible.

Comment: Try to change  **app:showAsAction="ifRoom"** instead  of  **app:showAsAction="never"**

Comment: This also doesn't work. My question is Menu and menu items are not visible on this activity when i open on mobile and when i open in emulator both menu and menu items i can see. How menu will be visible on this activity when i run on mobile. Please advise